# AlarmManager set as PM firing at AM time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

### The problem

I'm using Android's `AlarmManager` to fire a notification on my app periodically based on a time set by the user on a settings screen. I've followed [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms) to implement that. It's done like the snippet below:

```
fun setDailyAlarm(time: Calendar, id: Int) {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))
        set(Calendar.MINUTE, time.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
    }
    val pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    alarmManager.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        cal.timeInMillis,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        pi
    )
}
```

I'm also using the [Material Dialogs library](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) to invoke a time dialog, as follows:

```
MaterialDialog(this).show {
    // time here is a Calendar instance
    timePicker { _, time ->
        setDailyAlarm(time, ALARM_ID)
    }
}
```

The screen looks like the example below:

[image: Settings Screen]

The alarm itself is firing, but there's a weird bug happening.

Say that it's 9 PM and I set the alarm to 10 AM. I believe the expected behavior should be to fire the alarm the next day at 10 AM but once the clock reaches 10 PM *sometimes* I get a "false positive". (By *sometimes* I mean that this behavior is not even consistent. I managed to replicate it a few times, and my clients also complained about it).

**Note:** The app's minimum API level is 21.

### What I've tried so far

At first, I thought the calendar object might've been getting the wrong AM/PM flag, or the `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` property might've been wrong, but when I checked those values in the debugger everything seemed to be fine. So now I'm clueless to what the problem might be.

Is there something that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution to this problem.

After doing some tests I noticed that the problem only happened when I set the time to something previous to the current hour. Then it occurred to me that perhaps the `AlarmManager` might automatically fire "old alarms" so that might've been why I was getting that false positive.

Then I changed my `setDailyAlarm()` function to the snippet below:

```
fun setDailyAlarm(time: Calendar, id: Int) {
    val now = Calendar.getInstance()

    val cal = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))
        set(Calendar.MINUTE, time.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
    }

    if (time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) <= now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
    }

    val pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    alarmManager.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        cal.timeInMillis,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        pi
    )
}
```

**TL;DR:** I'm checking whether or not the chosen time is before the current time, and if that's the case I add one day to the `Calendar` instance before creating the `PendingIntent`. It seems to have solved the issue since the alarm is not firing at the wrong time anymore.